# Libudev and AT Commands

Tags: c++, c, usb, modem, at-command

I was searching how to send and receive SMS and I have searched a lot starting with how to do it on Linux. All I have found is libudev. I'm confortable with C/C++ so I hope it will fit me. However I'm not sure if libudev can enable me connect to a phone/modem and allow me send commands, So I though I would ask here:
Is libudev+AT commands a good option? If yes I would appreciate tutorials on how to send command to a USB Modem/Phone. It is C/C++ of course
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first clarify few things:

- libudev is a C library which provides interface to [udev](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Udev).
- udev is a device manager in Linux. It takes care of managing all of those device file nodes in `/dev`.
- udev can be used for example for querying or monitoring devices
- libudev (or udev) has nothing to do with modems, per se

So, back to your question. You can use libudev to find the modem among your other devices programmatically. In this case, udev might have created something like `/dev/ttyUSB0` for that device. You can also use `udevadm` command line tool for querying devices.

When you've got the right device, sending commands to your modem via serial interface is just a matter of writing to that device file. Web is full of examples of that:

- http://www.roman10.net/?p=14
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO.html

Comment: great comment. I have just started checking in for few hours. Let me read links

Answer (score 2):

Some years ago, I wrote a simple program that send and receive sms using a serial port under linux.
I had to format a PDU message, and then send it throught the serial port using standar AT commands.
I used an useful software called PDUSPY: http://www.nobbi.com/pduspy.html
You can find lot of info searching "PDU SMS format" in google.
I don't believe you need extra libraries like libudev to access your ports.
Why don't you try to play with minicom to test your AT commands an serial ports?.

You can list your available serial ports making a "dmesg | grep -i tty" in the command line.

Good luck.

Comment: I use laptop and have no serial port. Modem will be connected to USB port or did I misunderstand something in your answer?

Comment: Probably your usb modem this mapped as a tty device in the dev directory. Try the "dmesg | grep -i tty" to check if you can see a device called "/dev/ttyUSB" or similar. Then open a minicom with that device and try a simple "AT" to verify if modem responds. In linux, these devices are "always" managed like serial interfaces.

Comment: [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[   24.413671] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[22805.832156] cdc_acm 2-6:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

Comment: Looks like your modem could be /dev/ttyACM0. So install and use MINICOM to send your AT commands. MINICOM is a software similar to hyperterminal. Visit this link http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/modem-minicom.html